# How to fit multiple sequences with GMMHMM?

Tags: python, hmmlearn

I have a problem with the Python hmmlearn library. This is that I have several training sets and I would like to have one Gaussian mixture hmm model to fit them.

[Here is an example working with multiple sequences.](https://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html)

```
X = np.concatenate([X1, X2])
lengths = [len(X1), len(X2)]
hmm.GaussianHMM(n_components=3).fit(X, lengths)
```

When I change GaussianHMM to GMMHMM, it returns the following error:

```
hmm.GMMHMM(n_components=3).fit(X, lengths)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cody\workspace\QuickSilver_HMT\hmm_list_sqlite.py", line 141, in hmm_list_pickle
    hmm.GMMHMM(n_components=3).fit(X, lengths)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\hmmlearn\hmm.py", line 998, in fit
    raise ValueError("'lengths' argument is not supported yet")
ValueError: 'lengths' argument is not supported yet
```

How can one fit multiple sequences with GMMHMM?

Comment: Your example works for me with the X1, X2 values from the tutorial. Try updating hmmlearn to the latest version.

Comment: the latest version is 0.2.1?

Answer (score 0):

The current `master` version contains a re-write of `GMMHMM` which did not support multiple sequences at some point. Now it does, so updating should help, as @ppasler suggested.

The re-write is still a work-in-progress. Please report any issues you encounter on the hmmlearn [issue tracker](https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn/issues).

Comment: thanks a lot! I updated to the latest version 0.2.1 from Github,but it still doesn't work..

Comment: I updated to version 0.2.1,the same error is still returned.Is my updated version wrong?

Comment: Please try the latest version.